# As soon as I install nativescript-ui-listview it crashes with classnotfoundException

Tags: android, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I am using nativescript and as soon I install the listview plugin it crashes

If I run

```
tns run android
```

It compiles and run in the emulator.

I close the run with **CONTROL+C**

Then I install nativescript ui listview with:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
```

And after it installs and I try to run again with:

```
tns run android
```

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class:
>   com.telerik.widget.list.RadListView.ItemClickListener
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getClass(Generator.java:776)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.collectInterfaceMethods(Generator.java:703)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getPublicApi(Generator.java:227)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBinding(Generator.java:342)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBinding(Generator.java:133)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.processRows(Generator.java:172)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:90)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:66)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:47)

I have been looking around and I did not find any related issue.

It happen even before any import inside the app.

Comment: Are you using latest version of {N}? Did you try a clean build?

Comment: Hey @Manoj, yes I am using the latest. What do you mean with a clean build?

Comment: Try deleting node_modules & platforms folder then run the app again.

Comment: ok @Manoj I'm on it, thanks

Comment: Hey @Manoj thanks, It look it worked... I deleted node_modules, run npm install and then tns platform clean android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just to point out that after encountering the same problem, I just removed the android platform with `tns platform clean android` and it worked, it is not necessary to remove the node_modules folder.

Hope it helps the next ones to find this bug :)

Comment: Thanks you, your solution save a bit of time :D

Answer (score 1):

As @Manoj said just remove node_modules folder, then run

```
npm install
```

and after that run

```
tns platform clean android
```